# Creating associative array in a for-loop

Tags: javascript, xml, for-loop, multidimensional-array, associative-array

I have a big xml document that i'm trying to process into an array in javascript.

> ```
> <DR>
>    <C>
>      <SWDGDRC>
>        <CID>0</CID>
>        <V>06/01/2012 00:00:00</V>
>      </SWDGDRC>
>      <SWDGDRC>
>        <CID>1</CID>
>        <V>1131</V>
>      </SWDGDRC>
>      <SWDGDRC>
>        <CID>2</CID>
>        <V>28800</V>
>      </SWDGDRC>
>    </C>
>    <rowid>0</rowid>
> </DR>
> <DR>
>    <C>
>      <SWDGDRC>
>        <CID>0</CID>
>        <V>06/02/2012 00:00:00</V>
>      </SWDGDRC>
>      <SWDGDRC>
>        <CID>1</CID>
>        <V />
>      </SWDGDRC>
>      <SWDGDRC>
>        <CID>2</CID>
>        <V />
>      </SWDGDRC>
>    </C>
>    <rowid>1000</rowid>
> ```

It consists of multiple DR(datarow) and each DR has multiple C (columns) and a rowid.
I'm trying to loop all this data into an associative array:

```
    for(var i=0; i < DR.length; i++) {          // loop DR
        for(var j=0; j < DR[i].getElementsByTagName('C').length; j++) {    // loop C
            for(var k=0; k < DR[i].getElementsByTagName('C')[j].getElementsByTagName('SWDGDRC').length; k++) {   //loop SWDGDRC
                columnData[i] = {
                    "rowid": DR[i].getElementsByTagName('rowid')[0].textContent,
                    "column": {
                       columnID: DR[i].getElementsByTagName('C')[j].getElementsByTagName('SWDGDRC')[k].getElementsByTagName('CID')[0].textContent,
                       value:DR[i].getElementsByTagName('C')[j].getElementsByTagName('SWDGDRC')[k].getElementsByTagName('V')[0].textContent
                    }
               };
            }
        }
    }
```

The problem is I want to make an new array in the "column" key which loops all the C (columns) data so I can access this data using something like this: columnData[0]['column'][0]['columnID']

Comment: Have you thought about a recursive function already?

Comment: Could you change the structure of the source or is fixed for you?

Comment: @HMarioD source can not be changed, the data is pulled from an external webservice

Comment: Just now I put a possible answer, take a look.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for(var i=0; i < DR.length; i++) {          // loop DR
        for(var j=0; j < DR[i].getElementsByTagName('C').length; j++) {    // loop C
            columnData[i] = new Array(DR[i].getElementsByTagName('C')[j].getElementsByTagName('SWDGDRC').length);
            columnData[i] = {
                rowid: DR[i].getElementsByTagName('rowid')[0].textContent
            }
            for(var k=0; k < DR[i].getElementsByTagName('C')[j].getElementsByTagName('SWDGDRC').length; k++) {   //loop SWDGDRC
                columnData[i][k] = {
                    columnID: DR[i].getElementsByTagName('C')[j].getElementsByTagName('SWDGDRC')[k].getElementsByTagName('CID')[0].textContent,
                    value:DR[i].getElementsByTagName('C')[j].getElementsByTagName('SWDGDRC')[k].getElementsByTagName('V')[0].textContent
                };
            }
        }
    }
```

Fixed it by using the previous code. First I create a new array with the length of the array that i'm going to loop then I set the 'rowid' field. This way I can access my data by: columnData[0][0]['columnID']

Answer (score 0):

DRCollection[] -> DRCollection[0] = row_id, DRCollection[1] = colCollection[].